# How do restore an iOS 12 beta backup to a new iPhone running iOS 11?

Tags: iphone, restore, beta

I have an iPhone 7+ that is running iOS 12 beta. I got a new iPhone X and I want to have it mirror the 7+ by restoring the X from the backup. When I try to do this process, it seems that the X gets the OS wiped and restored to iOS 11, there it is not possible to restore the iOS 12 backup. Is there another way of doing this? Or a workaround? Help! Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to restore a beta backup to a different iPhone.  How are you trying to do the backup/restore?  Have you tried just installing the beta on the X first and then trying the restore?

Comment: Thx for the response. I ended up downgrading back to iOS 11 and was then able to restore another iOS 11 back-up.

Comment: I thought what you were asking about is how to restore iOS 12 beta from one device to another device?  Did you really just want to restore a backup of iOS 11 to another device?

Answer (score 4):

I restored an iPhone X from a iOS 12 beta iCloud backup.

Hardware: iPhone X factory reset to iOS 11.

Steps:

1. Enrolled device into the beta program, installed beta profile and allowed iOS upgrade. After restart pass through all intros to home screen.

   Note: Restore from iCloud showed the iOS 12 backups but they are inaccessible.
2. Go to Settings -> General -> Reset, then tap **Erase all content and settings.**, confirm and restart. This reset the phone again but at the iOS12 level.
3. Proceed through intros and restore via the now accessible iOS 12 backup.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use newer iOS backups with older iOS versions. If you had an archived backup from iOS 11.4 or older, you can use it with your iPhone X. If not, then you have a few options:

- You can install iOS 12.0 Beta on your iPhone X. If you do that, you should be able to use your backup.
- You can downgrade your iPhone 7 to iOS 11.4, but I [don't recommend doing so](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/314162/255044).
- You can manually copy important files and photos from your phone.

**Beta software is not intended for daily use.**

Comment: Thx for the response. I was able to downgrade iOS without and data loss issues. I did the restore and could potentially get back on the iOS 12 beta when I want.

Comment: You should not install beta software on your main device. If you really want to test beta software, you should use a seperate device. I am not saying you can't use your main device, but if you use beta software on it, you have the risk of losing all of your data. And always make a backup of your data before you install beta software, and archive that backup.

Answer (score 0):

Nope... Cannot restore from a beta backup to a new iDevice.  By erasing all content and settings you also erase the profile that runs the Beta on your iDevice.  Therefore, it will not ask you to upgrade, nor will it allow you to restore because the Beta version is newer than the version that you have.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this can help, but you could try to use your Apple ID to Login to your iCloud data base, of cause, not all the data you could restore but some of the information such as the contact, message, or if you do have iCloud photo, then sure you will have those photos back after you sign in your Apple ID, and download all the apps you need for daily need.

but the first thing first, if you have your data on iCloud